# C++ pass memory allocated / array by reference

Tags: c++

**SOLVED**

I am writing a interface to an existing lib that handles struct bwords (see code below), and would like to offer the possibility to call some check functions on the bword itself, or on a string of bytes (a bword member) :

```
#include <cstdio> 

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef struct bwordSt { ushort nbLetters;  byte *L; } bword;

template<typename T, size_t N>
  ushort checkBwL(T (&wL)[N], ushort wSz) {
  return 0;
}

ushort checkBwL(const byte* const &wL, ushort wSz) {
  return 0;
}

ushort checkBw(const bword &bw) {   
  return checkBwL(bw.L, bw.nbLetters);  
}

int main() {
  ushort n;
  byte fL[2] = {0, 1};
  n = checkBwL(fL, 2);  // calls the template function

  bword bW = {2, new byte[3]};
  bW.L[0] = 0; bW.L[1] = 1; bW.L[2] = 2; 
  n = checkBwL(bW.L, 3);  // calls the non-template function
  n = checkBw(bW);        // calls the non-template function

  return n;
}
```

The string of bytes can be huge, so I'd like to pass by reference. And I did it.

The only way I found to offer a uniform interface was to duplicate the code of the base check function (checkBwL) in a template (for arrays[byte]) and an overload (for byte*), which is ugly and forces me to maintain two basically identical (big) functions.

Any way around this ?

**SOLUTION**

No need for the template function, just don't forget the `const` before the `&` in argument specification `const byte* const &wL`

Comment: what does checkBWL do?

Comment: @ NathanOliver : fixed. @Richard : lots of things, the struct is actually much richer than that.

Comment: Why don't you just call non-template function from template function?

Comment: It looks like you expect `checkBw()` should call templated version of `checkBwL()`. But it will not. What use case are you expect for templated version?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you need the template function and I can't.  It is basically the same as your non-template function and the non-template version should work with a pointer or an array.

Comment: @NathanOliver: you're absolutely right ! I just tested and it works. I thought the non-template function would refuse an array[byte] as argument, because of the compiler error message ; it was actually only due to the fact that I forgot the const before & in "const byte* const &wL" in my project !

Answer (score 1):

The key to success is delegation:

```
#include <cstdio> 

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef struct bwordSt { ushort nbLetters;  byte *L; } bword;

ushort check_impl(ushort length, const byte* buffer)
{
    // do your actual checking here
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
auto checkBw(T (&wL)[N], ushort wSz) -> ushort
{
    return wSz == (N * sizeof(T)) &&  // assuming no null terminator 
    check_impl(wSz, reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(wL));
}

ushort checkBw(const byte* const &wL, ushort wSz) {
  return check_impl(wSz, wL);
}

ushort checkBw(const bword &bw) {   
  return check_impl(bw.nbLetters, bw.L);  
}

int main() {
  ushort n;
  byte fL[2] = {0, 1};
  n = checkBw(fL, 2);  // calls the template function

  bword bW = {2, new byte[3]};
  bW.L[0] = 0; bW.L[1] = 1; bW.L[2] = 2; 
  n = checkBw(bW.L, 3);  // calls the non-template function
  n = checkBw(bW);        // calls the non-template function

  return n;
}
```

Comment: Actually there is no need for a template function, as stated by NathanOliver above. The technique you're suggesting is very interesting though, although my C++11 compiler dislikes this about it : test.cpp:14:36: error: ‘checkBw’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type : auto checkBw(...   Thanks anyway, that's something to remember.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 ah ok, I've used a c++14 feature there. My apologies.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 ...and edit made to make it c++11 compatible.